# Is createdAt fields in MySQL tables edittable?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm working with mySql database and I saw that createdAt field was auto created.

Can I modify this value? 
I want this field is not edittable, like a constant from the time it was initted.

If it is edittable, how can I make it not edittable?

(I'm working with Sequelizejs)

Answer (score 0):

`updatedAt` and `createdAt` is auto created by Sequelizejs by default , as a result of default value of `timestamps: true` ,

createdAt get the value of time of insertion , it will never updated by it self

So if you write a query to update createdAt , it will be updated , and no one can stop that ,

But generally , no user passes the updatedAt and createdAt fields , 
Those are handled automatically by the Sequelizejs and this is how it should work.

> **Not Suggested** but still if you want any field to make readonly , you
>   can add custom validations via model or use **[PLUGIN](http://node-sequelize-noupdate-attributes)**.